# Find combinations of words in two vectors

Tags: string, r, vector

I have a long list of words contained in two vectors

The first vector looks like this:

```
x <- c("considerably", "much", "far")
```

The second vector looks like this:

```
y <- c("higher", "lower")
```

I need a vector returned, which lists possible combinations of words from each vector. Using `x` and `y`, I would need this vector returned

```
[1] "considerably higher" "considerably lower"  "much higher"         "much lower"         
[5] "far higher"          "far lower"
```

Therefore words in vector x must come before words in vector y. Is there a quick way of doing this?

Comment: +1 for example input and desired output (a relief after some recent questions from other OPs!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `outer` with `paste`, I think that will be quite quick!

```
as.vector( t( outer( x , y , "paste"  ) ) )
# [1] "considerably higher" "considerably lower"  "much higher"        
# [4] "much lower"          "far higher"          "far lower"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `expand.grid`.

```
sort(apply(X = expand.grid(x, y), MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) paste(x[1], x[2], sep = " ")))
```