# Find all combinations of words in a vector

Tags: r, combinations

I have a vector of words:

```
str <- c("The", "Cat", "Jumped")
```

I would like to find all combinations of words and insert a "+" between any combinations of more than one, similar to:

```
paste(str, collapse = " + ")
# [1] "The + Cat + Jumped"
```

My desired output would be:

```
want <- c("The", "Cat", "Jumped", 
          "The + Cat", "The + Jumped",
          "Cat + Jumped",
          "The + Cat + Jumped")
```

Also note I need only combinations so order doesn't matter and either `"The + Cat"` or `"Cat + The"` is fine, but I do not want both.

---

I tried some approaches with `combn` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56527791/how-to-get-list-of-all-combinations-of-pairs-of-character-strings-in-r)), `outer` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028481/find-combinations-of-words-in-two-vectors)), `expand.grid` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705153/generate-list-of-all-possible-combinations-of-elements-of-vector)), and following @Akrun's suggestion on a similar question [r - Get different combinations of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122696/get-different-combinations-of-words) but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unlist(lapply(seq(str), combn, x=str, paste, collapse=' + '))

[1] "The"                "Cat"                "Jumped"             "The + Cat"          "The + Jumped"      
[6] "Cat + Jumped"       "The + Cat + Jumped"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `combn` for all possible sizes, and then collapse the results yourself

```
str <- c("The", "Cat", "Jumped")
Map(function(i) combn(str, i, simplify = FALSE), seq_along(str)) |>
  unlist(recursive=FALSE) |> 
  sapply(paste, collapse=" + ")
# [1] "The"                "Cat"                "Jumped"            
# [4] "The + Cat"          "The + Jumped"       "Cat + Jumped"      
# [7] "The + Cat + Jumped"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can play a trick with `intToBits` like below

```
lapply(
  1:(2^length(str) - 1),
  function(k) {
    paste0(str[which(intToBits(k) == 1)], collapse = " + ")
  }
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1] "The"

[[2]]
[1] "Cat"

[[3]]
[1] "The + Cat"

[[4]]
[1] "Jumped"

[[5]]
[1] "The + Jumped"

[[6]]
[1] "Cat + Jumped"

[[7]]
[1] "The + Cat + Jumped"
```

Comment: What is inttobits doing in this context!? If you could add a brief explanation that would be lovely :-)

Comment: @Mark `intToBits` produces a binary masking to make the combinations. For example, `1` -> `001`, `2` -> `010`, `3` -> `011`, ...., `7` -> `111`

Answer (score 3):

Here is tidyverse variation of @MrFlick s code:

```
library(tidyverse)

str <- c("The", "Cat", "Jumped")

map(1:length(str), function(i) {
  combn(str, i, simplify = FALSE) %>%
    map(~paste(., collapse = " + "))
  }) %>%
  unlist(recursive = FALSE) %>% 
  unlist()
```

```
[1] "The"                "Cat"               
[3] "Jumped"             "The + Cat"         
[5] "The + Jumped"       "Cat + Jumped"      
[7] "The + Cat + Jumped"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `powerSet` function from the `rje` package:

```r
lapply(rje::powerSet(str), paste, collapse = " + ")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] ""
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "The"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "Cat"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "The + Cat"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "Jumped"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "The + Jumped"
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] "Cat + Jumped"
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] "The + Cat + Jumped"
```

N.B. The first element corresponds to the empty set. See the wiki for the  [Power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) for more information.